# How to use ActionController::Live along with Resque + Redis (for Chat application)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redis, resque

I am trying to build a chat feature for my rails application. I am using `ActionController::Live`, `Puma`, `Resque`, `Redis` for this. So basically in this case, redis `subscribe` method is running in background using `resque`.
So far what i have done is whenever a user enters a text in below form field i.e. chat box

```
    <%= form_tag chat_box_publish_path, method: :get do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: "form-control", id: "chatSearchBox",
            placeholder: 'Search' %>
    <% end %>
```

..the request is coming to `Publish` method in `ChatBoxController`.

```
def publish
    $redis.publish("chat_message:1:1", "#{params[:query]}")
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render nothing: true}
    end
end
```

..now i have a below background `Resque` job running with below code for testing purposes. So whenever a chat message is posted, its printing the `data` which is fine. But how can i add `ActionController::Live` feature to the background job ? or how do i go about this implementation ? Need help with this design.

```
class ChatBoxInitiator
    @queue = :chat_box_initiator

    private
    def self.perform
    $redis.subscribe('chat_message:1:1') do |on|
            on.message do |event, data|
                puts "====#{data}"
                return data
            end
        end
    end
end
```

and i want to show the `Server Sent Events(SSE)` along with `ActionController::Live` for notifications in `Users/show` page

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you are simply trying to build a chat web app, why do you need `resque`? What's the role of `resque` in all of this?

Comment: hey @Sheharyar actually thats one of my questions ..i am not sure whether i am doing it right or not as well..i am trying to build single page application...the main page is `users/show` and i have `ChatBoxController` to use redis and update on `users/show` page itself...any idea on how to do ?

Answer (score 13):

#### Pre-Reqs:

- Ruby 2.0.0+
- Rails 4.0.0+
- Redis
- Puma

---

#### Initializer:

Create a `redis.rb` initializer file in the `config/initializers` directory, globalizing an instance of `redis`. It's also a good idea to set up a `heartbeat` thread (Anything from 5 seconds to 5 minutes is okay, depending on your requirements):

```rb
$redis = Redis.new

heartbeat_thread = Thread.new do
  while true
    $redis.publish("heartbeat","thump")
    sleep 15.seconds
  end
end

at_exit do
  heartbeat_thread.kill
  $redis.quit
end
```

---

#### Controller:

You need to add two methods to your `ChatController`, `pub` and `sub`. The role of `pub` is to publish chat events and messages to `redis`, and `sub` to subscribe to these events. It should look something like this:

```rb
class ChatController < ApplicationController
    include ActionController::Live

    skip_before_filter  :verify_authenticity_token

    def index
    end

    def pub
        $redis.publish 'chat_event', params[:chat_data].to_json
        render json: {}, status: 200
    end

    def sub
        response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/event-stream"

        redis = Redis.new
        redis.subscribe(['chat_event', 'heartbeat']) do |on|
            on.message do |event, data|
                response.stream.write "event: #{event}\ndata: #{data}\n\n"
            end
        end
    rescue IOError
        logger.info "Stream Closed"
    ensure
        redis.quit
        response.stream.close
    end
end
```

In your `routes`, make ***pub*** a `POST` and ***sub*** a `GET`, and match the path to something like `/chat/publish` and `/chat/subscribe`.

---

#### Coffeescript / Javascript:

Assuming your actual webpage for the chat app is at `/chat`, you need to write some *Javascript* to actually send and receive chat messages.

For ease of understanding, let's suppose your webpage only has a textbox and a button. Hitting the button should publish the content of the textbox to the chat stream, we can do that using AJAX:

```
$('button#send').click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    $.ajax '/chat/publish',
        type: 'POST'
        data:
            chat_data: {
                message: $("input#message").val()
                timestamp: $.now()
        error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
            console.log "Failed: " + textStatus 
        success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
            console.log "Success: " + textStatus
```

Now, you need to be able to subscribe and receive the chat messages as well.  You need to use `EventSource` for this. Using *EventSource*, open a channel for SSE so that you can receive events, and use that data to update the view. In this example, we will only log them to the javascript console.

The code should look something like this:

```
$(document).ready ->
    source = new EventSource('/chat/subscribe')
    source.addEventListener 'chat_event', (e) ->
        console.log(e.data)
```

***Note:*** *Place both of the code blocks above in your `controllername.coffee` file, for this example it should be `chat.js.coffee`* in your `app/assets/javascript` directory. You also need to make sure it's being loaded in the asset pipeline. `require` it in your `application.js` file (if you aren't already calling `require tree .`).

---

#### Enable Parallel Requests:

In your development environment, you'll have to enable parallel requests by adding these two lines to your `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
config.preload_frameworks = true
config.allow_concurrency = true
```

Now fire up your browser, browse to `/chat` and see the magic. When you type a message and click the button, the message will be received by all instances of that webpage.

---

Well this is how you make a basic chat application in `rails` using `ActionController::Live` and `Redis`. The final code would obviously be very different depending on your requirements but this should get you started.

Some more resources you should check out:

- Tender Love Making - [Is it Live?](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html)
- Railscasts - [#401 - ActionController::Live](http://railscasts.com/episodes/401-actioncontroller-live)
- SitePoint - [Mini Chat with Rails and SSEs](http://www.sitepoint.com/mini-chat-rails-server-sent-events/)
- Github - [mohanraj-ramanujam / live-stream](https://github.com/mohanraj-ramanujam/live-stream)
- Thoughtbot - [Chat Example using SSEs](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/chat-example-app-using-server-sent-events)

Comment: hi, In my application, i have only single page which is `users/show` and in this page i have chat box form mentioned in my above question. So when user posts a chat text in that..it goes into `chat/publish` controller and publishes. Now how can another user get notification of new chat message in `users/show` page ? Please let me know if my question is clear ..as my explaining capacity is little poor.

Comment: @rahul, i understood your question, and my answer does exactly that. Please see the javascript section, on how other users can receive chat messages

Comment: Even though I wrote this answer from memory, i just tried it on my local machine and can guarantee you that its working.

Comment: hi, its not working for me...being in `/users/show` page and submitting my chat message to `/chat_box/publish` from `/users/show` page...how can i receive a notification in `users/show` when` chat_box#publish` method is not getting called at all? and in my case shall i place `event source js` inside users view ?

Comment: Hey, sorry. I didn't notice that you left a comment until I randomly came back to this answer. This is `coffeescript`, you'll need to place it in a `chat.coffee` file and `require` it in your `application.js` (if you are not already using `require tree .`)

Comment: @Sheharyar thanks for your answer in great detail. Especially thank you for  the **Enable Parallel Requests** part. I tried to create a rails chat app using redis without knowledge of parallel requests feature, so it kept being blocked whenever I tried.