# unable to handle disconnected clients in SSE

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, redis, publish-subscribe, server-sent-events

I'm trying to add SSE functionality to my server application using Redis PubSub, guided by many articles i.e:
[how-to-use-actioncontollerlive-along-with-resque-redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150274/how-to-use-actioncontrollerlive-along-with-resque-redis-for-chat-applicatio).

The server is hosted in Heroku, thus heartbeating is necessary as well.

```
...
sse = SSE.new(response.stream)
begin
    redis = Redis.new(:url => ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL'])
    redis.subscribe(<UUID>, HEARTBEAT_CHANNEL) do |on|
        on.message do |channel, data|
            begin
                if channel == HEARTBEAT_CHANNEL
                    sse.write('', event: "hb")
                else
                  sse.write(data, event: "offer_update")
                end
            rescue StandardError => e #I'll call this section- "internal rescue"
                puts "Internal: #{$!}"
                redis.quit
                sse.close
                puts "SSE was closed
            end
        end
    end
rescue StandardError => e  #I'll call this section- "external rescue"
    puts "External: #{$!}"
ensure
    redis.quit
    sse.close
    puts "sse was closed"
end
```

The questions:

1. **I didn't see the "Internal rescue" in any place over the net talking about SSE**. but I don't get who can catch an exception if raised by the `sse.write`? The common scenario is that HB is sent while client isn't connected anymore which makes this section so critical (`"Internal: client disconnected"` is appeared). Am I right?
2. **In which case will the "external rescue" be triggered?** Does a client disconnection cause `sse.write` to raise an exception in the "inner block" (inside the on.message body)? because it was never caught by the external rescue when I tried to simulate it tens of times.
3. This code suffers as well. `redis.quit` in the internal rescue section raises another exception which is caught by the external rescue statement: `External: undefined method 'disconnect' for #<Redis::SubscribedClient:0x007fa8cd54b820>`. So - how should it done? how can I recognize ASAP a client disconnection in order to free the memory&socket?
4. How can it be that exceptions raised by the `sse.write` have NOT been  caught by the external rescue (as it should be from beginning) while another error (described in my 3rd question) has been caught? all of this code (outer+inner sections) is running in the same thread, right? I'd be happy for a deep explaination.

Answer (score 0):

You catch the exception inside the `subscribe`, and so redis doesn't know about it and will not stop it's inner loop properly. `redis.quit` will cause it to crash and stop since it cannot keep waiting for a message. This is obviously not a good way to do it.

If your code throws an exception inside the `subscribe` it will cause redis to gracefully unsubscribe and your exception can be rescued outside, as in your "external rescue".

Another point is that you shouldn't catch exceptions without fully handling them, and you should never catch generic exceptions without re-raising them. In this case you can safely let the `ClientDisconnected` exception bubble to Rails' code.

Here's how your controller's code should look like:

```
def subscribe
  sse = SSE.new(response.stream)
  redis = Redis.new(:url => ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL'])
  redis.subscribe(<UUID>, HEARTBEAT_CHANNEL) do |on|
    on.message do |channel, data|
      if channel == HEARTBEAT_CHANNEL
        sse.write('', event: "hb")
      else
        sse.write(data, event: "offer_update")
      end
    end
  end
ensure
  redis.quit if reddis # might not have had a chance to initialize yet
  sse.close if sse # might not have had a chance to initialize yet
  puts "sse was closed"
end
```